# Convergence or divergence of $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} (-1)^r \frac{r^2}{2r^{5/2}-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to find if the following series converges or diverges:
 $$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} (-1)^r \frac{r^2}{2r^{5/2}-1}$$

Now my first idea was to reduce it to 
$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} (-1)^r \frac{1}{2r^{1/2}-r^{-2}}$$ and see that $\lim\limits_{r \to \infty} a_r = 0.$ This suggests that the series may or may not converge. Now I tried using ratio and root tests, the ratio test doesn't work and for the root test I get the following limit:

$$\limsup_{r \to \infty} \frac{1}{\left(2\sqrt{r}- r^{-2}\right)^{1/r}}$$ But I am stuck there. Is any other way to prove this? Might be easy but I can't see. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can someone also help me to give a suitable title? or is this OK?

Comment: Do you know the alternating series test?

Comment: I forgot that thank you. This solves it. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$a_r=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} (-1)^r \frac{r^2}{2r^{\frac{5}{2}}-1}$$
is an alternating series

The series converges if you can prove, where

$$b_r = \frac{r^2}{2r^{\frac{5}{2}}-1},$$
that

$$ \lim_{r\to\infty} b_r = 0$$
and $\{b_r\}$ is decreasing.

--

Comment: @PeterForeman yeah, sorry for the typo.

Comment: I checked that the terms are not decreasing always. So does it mean that the series diverges?

Comment: @Rick How did you come to that conclusion? The derivative of the terms is strictly negative for all $r\ne1$.

Comment: Sorry, I see it now, I had wrong conclusions.